# Is there a way to Prevent Meshes from going through one another?

Tags: mesh, physics

I want to treat my individual meshes as solid objects where the other mesh is unable to pass through them. If I were to push the mesh into them for instance, it would stop at the border of the mesh instead of continuing through.

Is there a way to make these meshes have these "barriers" so to speak?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to while you're editing the scene, this isn't really possible. For animations, you should research Blender's Physics Simulation capabilities.